# R: filter a vector of words by letter disimilarity

Tags: r, vector, conditional-statements

I am creating a vector of words using the following command:

```
DNA <- c("A","G","T","C")
randomDNA <- c()

for (i in 1:96){
  randomDNA[i] <- paste0(sample(DNA, 6, replace = TRUE), sep = "", collapse = "")
}
```

This will create a vector with 96 elements. words containing either A,T,C,G.
How can I:

**A.** insert in the loop a condition that will keep words that have at least 3 differences from each other, **keeping** the size of the vector constant?

**B.** do the same but removing replicates of the same word.
Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

Based on your attempt on `Hamming distance`, you can try the code below

```
Humm_gt3 <- DNAall[1]
for (i in 2:length(DNAall)) {
  split_vector <- strsplit(DNAall[i], "")[[1]]
  flag_gt3 <- TRUE
  for (j in 1:length(Humm_gt3)) {
    split_vector2 <- strsplit(Humm_gt3[j], "")[[1]]
    flag_gt3 <- flag_gt3 & (sum(split_vector != split_vector2) >= 3)
  }
  if (flag_gt3) Humm_gt3 <- c(Humm_gt3, DNAall[i])
}
```

or a lighter version (more efficient)

```
Humm_gt3 <- DNAall[1]
for (i in DNAall[-1]) {
  v <- utf8ToInt(i)
  flag_gt3 <- TRUE
  for (j in Humm_gt3) {
    if (sum(v != utf8ToInt(j)) < 3) {
      flag_gt3 <- FALSE
      break
    }
  }
  if (flag_gt3) Humm_gt3 <- c(Humm_gt3, i)
}
```

which gives

```
> Humm_gt3
 [1] "AAAAAA" "GGGAAA" "TTTAAA" "CCCAAA" "TGAGAA" "CAGGAA" "ACTGAA" "GTCGAA"
 [9] "CTATAA" "TCGTAA" "GATTAA" "AGCTAA" "GCACAA" "ATGCAA" "CGTCAA" "TACCAA"
[17] "CGAAGA" "TAGAGA" "GCTAGA" "ATCAGA" "GAAGGA" "AGGGGA" "CTTGGA" "TCCGGA"
[25] "ACATGA" "GTGTGA" "TGTTGA" "CACTGA" "TTACGA" "CCGCGA" "AATCGA" "GGCCGA"
[33] "GTAATA" "ACGATA" "CATATA" "TGCATA" "CCAGTA" "TTGGTA" "GGTGTA" "AACGTA"
[41] "TAATTA" "CGGTTA" "ATTTTA" "GCCTTA" "AGACTA" "GAGCTA" "TCTCTA" "CTCCTA"
[49] "TCAACA" "CTGACA" "AGTACA" "GACACA" "ATAGCA" "GCGGCA" "TATGCA" "CGCGCA"
[57] "GGATCA" "AAGTCA" "CCTTCA" "TTCTCA" "CAACCA" "TGGCCA" "GTTCCA" "ACCCCA"
```

---

## Previous Answer

1. You can try to build all combinations of `DNA`, i.e., `DNAall`, using `expand.grid` like below

```
DNAall <- do.call(paste0, expand.grid(rep(list(DNA), 6)))
```

2. Then, you can use `for` loop and `adist` to select the DNA sequence that has distance `>=3` to all other selected ones in `DNA_gt3`

```
DNA_gt3 <- DNAall[1]
for (dna in DNAall[-1]) {
  if (all(adist(dna, DNA_gt3) >= 3)) DNA_gt3 <- c(DNA_gt3, dna)
}
```

3. Finally, you will obtain a complete set of DNAs that have distance at least 3 between any pair  in `DNA_gt3`, i.e.,

```
> DNA_gt3
 [1] "AAAAAA" "GGGAAA" "TTTAAA" "CCCAAA" "TGAGAA" "CAGGAA" "ACTGAA" "GTCGAA"
 [9] "CTATAA" "GATTAA" "GCACAA" "TACCAA" "CGAAGA" "GCTAGA" "ATCAGA" "AGGGGA"
[17] "TATGGA" "GTGTGA" "TCCTGA" "TTACGA" "CCGCGA" "GGCCGA" "GTAATA" "TGCATA"
[25] "CCAGTA" "AACGTA" "TAGTTA" "CGTTTA" "ATTCTA" "TCAACA" "AGTACA" "GCGGCA"
[33] "CTTGCA" "GGATCA" "CACTCA" "AAGCCA" "AGCAAG" "TCGGAG" "ATGTAG" "CCTTAG"
[41] "GTTCAG" "GAAAGG" "TTGAGG" "ATAGGG" "GGTGGG" "CACGGG" "AATTGG" "TCTCGG"
[49] "AAGATG" "CTCATG" "CGGGTG" "TTTGTG" "GCCGTG" "TGATTG" "CAACTG" "TACACG"
[57] "GAGTCG" "ACCTCG" "AGACCG" "CTGCCG" "CGTGAT" "AGATAT" "GCCTAT" "GAGCAT"
[65] "ATCCAT" "CAGAGT" "TGCGGT" "TAATGT" "CTTCGT" "ACAATT" "GGTATT" "GAAGTT"
[73] "ATGGTT" "TCTTTT" "CCCCTT" "TGGACT" "GTCACT" "TTAGCT" "CCATCT" "CGGTAC"
[81] "ACGCAC" "TCAGGC" "GAGGGC" "AGCTGC" "AAACGC" "TGGCGC" "TAAATC" "CATGTC"
[89] "ATATTC" "GCGTTC" "TTCCTC" "CTAACC" "GATACC" "CGCGCC" "TTGTCC" "CCTCCC"
```

---

**For your second objective**

Since `DNA_gt3` is a complete set, if you want to see which unique elements in `randomDNA` fall within this set, you can use

```
unique(randomDNA[randomDNA %in% DNA_gt3])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
My implementation of the distance derives from the following code, is it possible to use that one instead of the adist? In reality it does not really matter but I would like to use the same approach?:
`for (i in 1:length(DNA_gt3)){
  split_vector <- strsplit(DNA_gt3[i], "")[[1]]
  for (j in 1:length(DNA_gt3)){
    split_vector2 <- strsplit(DNA_gt3[j], "")[[1]]
    #Hamming distance is calculated as:
    Humm[i,j] <- sum(split_vector != split_vector2)
  }
}`

Comment: @sunta3iouxos Yes, I think Hamming distance also applies here. The key point is the idea of how to ensure the distance between any pair, and it should work for any other type of distance measure.

Comment: In your code you interrogate each entry in the loop "dna" Vs the growing "DNA_gt3" vector. The adist() works well in an vector Vs vector manner. The Hamming (my implementation) works in a element Vs element manner. **BUT** I can not make it to work (not good in nested for loops). the following does not work that well.`for (i in 1:length(DNAall)) { split_vector <- strsplit(DNAall[i], "")[[1]]  for (j in 1:length(DNAall)) {split_vector2 <- strsplit(DNAall[j], "")[[1]]  if (all(sum(split_vector != split_vector2) >=3))
      **Humm_gt3[i] <- DNAall[i]}}**`

Comment: @sunta3iouxos Could you create a new post for your new question? It's difficult to follow what happened if you have your question in comments.

Comment: any clue on what I should ask, the title will be the same, should I add something like not using adist and using Hamming? Sorry for this awkward question!

Comment: @sunta3iouxos You can see my updated answer with Hamming distance

Comment: This `flag_gt3 <- TRUE` , this is what I was looking for. It never crossed my mind! Thank you also for the more efficient way.

Comment: Interesting note.
Using adist the >= 3 vector is of 96 elements
using the sum( ) I get 64 elements.
Is this to be expected or is there an error somewhere? I was expecting a vector of 96 elements

Comment: @sunta3iouxos `adist` applies "generalized Levenshtein (edit) distance", which is different from "Hamming distance". For example, `adist("GAG","AGA")` gives distance `2`, while the Hamming distance is `3`. This will result in difference in the size of complete set.

Comment: That is the thing. From all the 4096 possibilities of the "a,T,C,G" we get back less using the Hamming distance than the adist, that should give less? Maybe we are getting a bit off the original question, but I believe it is relevant.

Comment: @sunta3iouxos Yes, from the definitions of Hamming and Levenshtein distances, Hamming distance counts on every single "bit", which is a tougher constraint than Levenshtein, thus giving less.